# implement *nix find utility in Go

Tags: go, flags

I'm trying to build a linux utility and I want to parse the below command.

```
go-find / -name "filename"
```

the above is supposed to search given "filename" in the given path(/).

But the code is not able to parse the flag since it is encountering non-flag argument before any flag value to parse.  To  help make sense of it. This is written is flag package documentation.

"Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--"."

I am thinking any other workaround is possible?

Comment: Create a [flag set](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#NewFlagSet); define flags in that set;  parse os.Args[2:].

Comment: We cannot answer without seeing your code. Post a [mcve]

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks for the input. I came up with similar approach after little bit if thinking!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the idea was not to ask for code rather share some thoughts on how how to implement this thing. Cannot understand why people jump so early to negate efforts made to ask questions:)

Answer (score 0):

Use [flag.FlagSet](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#NewFlagSet) to parse flags without the 'path' variable and [os.Args](https://pkg.go.dev/os#pkg-variables) to parse the 'path' variable manually:

```
type Flags struct {
    Path string
    Name string
}

func main() {
    args := os.Args
    if len(args) < 4 { // the program name is the first argument
        log.Fatal("not enough arguments")
    }

    var (
        fs = flag.NewFlagSet(args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
        f  Flags
    )
    fs.StringVar(&f.Name, "name", "", "file name")
    err := fs.Parse(args[2:]) // parse flags without the program name and the 'path' argument
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    f.Path = args[1] // get 'path' argument

    fmt.Println(f)
    
    // search algorithm ...
}
```

```
{/ filename}
```